# Can not inherit a class in odoo js

Tags: javascript, odoo

> Inherited class undefined

I was trying to inherit a class in odoo js. After inherited, while printing console it gives undefined

```
odoo.define('tokio_marine.escalation_client_action', function (require) {
"use strict";

var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var mailChatAction = require('mail.chat_client_action');

console.log('mailChatAction',mailChatAction);
```

The console shows mailChatAction as undefined.
It was expected to print the class

Comment: Can you specify the odoo version ?

Comment: Version 10 odoo